# accept only num and dot when press

Tags: c#

hello i wanna understand this code .. i just take it copy past to my work space

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar > (char)Keys.D9 || e.KeyChar < (char)Keys.D0) && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back && e.KeyChar != '.')
    { 
        e.Handled = true; 
    }
    //Edit: Alternative
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking a key event is sent to a chain of event handlers. Whenever someone says "I've handled it", the chain stops. So, when the key press is outside the range of numbers and not backspace or decimal point, this code sets `e.Handled` to true and the chain stops. That means event handling stops and the key is not shown in the textbox.